# How to run php script with apache on debian

Tags: php, apache2.4, debian-jessie

I am using Apache2.4 php5 and Debian(jessie). php5 enabled. When i going to http://my_url/info.php browser is not give result? The code of php :

```
<?php
 phpinfo(); 
?>
```

1. Update and upgrade
2. Install packages of php
3. apache restart

but this is do not working

Comment: Hi there! Some more information about the kind of error you are receiving will help others help you

Comment: @Santaclaus i hope [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian) article from digital ocean helps you on how to set up

Comment: it do not working, too :(

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost/info.php

Comment: does your httpd process starts normally? If not, check the log files for errors.

Comment: I am not setting rule of folder.

Answer (score 0):

by default its working on http://localhost

if you want to working your own url so you have to do host entry in host file
which is located in /etc/hosts file
127.0.0.1 my_url